# radio frequency that the phone's cellular radio is using to talk to the tower / base station in Android

Tags: android, cellular-network

What I am looking for is the radio frequency that the phone's cellular radio is using to talk to the tower / base station. I need to Calculate the Frequency and display into my Android app.

Comment: uhmmm. not sure about exact problem. perhaps this class might help you in your endeavour: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html

Comment: NOt any luck, have checked these reference, may be there will be some Formulas for can calculate by doing some calculations using telephony references.